# Pushing stack function receives memory leak which I cannot find

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I have got a function which does different things to both a queue and a stack, such as pushing, peeking, popping, printing, initialising etc. I've done most of them, however, I'm getting a memory leak as well as a segmentation fault on the pop_stack function, and I am unsure why.

My code for the pop_stack function is this:

```
/* add entry to end of stack *stack */
/* allocate storage of data_size bytes in new entry */
/* copy data referenced by *data to entry */
/* return pointer to newly created entry */
/* print an error message and return if stack is NULL or empty */
/* or if data is NULL */
Node *push_stack(Stack *stack, void *data, size_t data_size)
{
    Node *new_node;
    Node *node;
    void *new_data;
    if (stack == NULL || data == NULL || stack->head == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "warning: unable to push stack.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    new_node = initialise_node();
    new_data = (void *)malloc(data_size);
    memcpy(new_data, data, data_size);
    new_node->data = new_data;
    return 0;

    if (stack->tail == NULL)
    {
        stack->head = new_node;
        stack->tail = new_node;
        new_node->data = new_data;
        return new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        node = stack->tail;
        stack->tail = new_node;
        new_node->prev = node;
        new_node->next = NULL;
        new_node->data = new_data;
    }
}
```

And the rest of the code for the stack is here:
    https://pastebin.com/zAFGdAbJ

The entire output of Valgrind for this is here: 
    https://pastebin.com/25LTHnMk

I don't have any free() in my pop_stack function, and this is because I have another file which does all the testing for this, and in this task, not all the frees are to be done by the program but by the user themselves, so by the test program rather than all being done within the functions. The main function for that file that i've got is here: https://pastebin.com/iZmn6nGd

Anyone able to help me out?

Comment: You have a fault in the `pop_stack` function but the code you show is for `push_stack`!

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your `return 0` is in the wrong place. You unconditionally return 0 (i.e. NULL), so the pointer `new_node` is torn down with the call stack, therefore leaking memory.